# Does the test and test tooling differ from Magento to other test tools or solutions?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management, test-planning, magento

I am on my way to one of my next Magento projects. Currently there is no test environment, no test days, no concepts or test plans. Even a team has to be set up first.

I have already worked a lot in the web area and would see no problem to test Magento in a normal way.

But is SoapUI, 
Postman (for API calls and collections), 
static code analysis via SonarQube, 
or Jmeter for load and performance test, 
security test procedures via Owasp ZAP enough?

What is possibly more special about Magento, what is different, which problems could expect me with the test procedures in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

Magento has its own "[testing guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/test/testing.html)" which seems to cover most if not all of these topics.

Magento also has its own Functional Testing Framework, which you should probably use as it will make live of future developers/testers easier which already know how to write functional tests for their product. See https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/introduction.html

For the rest Magento is a web-application writen in PHP. So most if not all web-testing and php-testing would translate to a Magento application.